# where to place jar in order to run a program from command-line?

Tags: java, classpath

this will sound silly but i am executing my code from command prompt and have to use a jar in my class.
I have placed my jar in lib folder of JDK..
but i am still getting error of file not found

any explanation??

**EDITED** : guys tried all but still not working

**EDIT 2** :i am trying to work as was told by this [link](http://sites.google.com/site/javascript4rhino/tutorials/compile-javascript-file) i am using **js-1.6R5.jar**

**Edit 3** : i undestand all the things you ppl have told but nothing working for me.. pls give me a link to upload my example that i can share with you all.

**Edit 4** : i am fed up by setting classpaths but its not working... i have SDK installed in my system, do i need an extra JDK to run my programs from command prompt??

Comment: Since you've commented that several of the given answers did not work, could you please post a more exact description of the problem and what you've tried? Particularly the full text of the error message could be useful to us.

Comment: Meaning no disrespect to others, but try to avoid using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, since your other programs might break without you knowing why (different versions of libraries can be loaded, etc.)

Comment: how about showing what exactly fails - i.e. what you enter in the command line.

Comment: Ok, what `jar` file are you using? Where is it located on your computer?

Comment: Can you tell a) What exactly you're typing into the command line?, b) what error message you get?, and c) what are the contents of the jar file (folder structure and packages)?

Comment: i wonder if the file is corrupted, bad format or something

Comment: @ J16- i have tried with 2-3 different jar files...
@ dspyz - i have provided the link in question and i am doing exactly the same the only different is folder is not in C: and is on desktop but i am taking that change into consideration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the jar to the class path by doing the following...

> java -classpath D:\myprogram;D:\myprogram\lib\supportLib.jar org.mypackage.HelloWorld

Please see [Wikipedia - Classpath_(Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Basic_usage)

Answer (score 2):

You can place it anywhere, as long is you include it in your classpath. See [Setting the Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for how to include jars in the classpath.

Have in mind that adding something in the JDK lib is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I can't see your attempts, so I can't help more.

Comment: Its very possible you are missing the required jar file. Some jar files depend on other which you also need to include in the class path.

Comment: @Paul- this is not the case. i have checked the jar in jar opener and its complete in itself

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `lib` folder in your application's directory and put `jar` files there, then make your application find them by adding `lib` to your application's classpath.

And, don't put your `jar` files in JDK's `lib` folder. It's not good practise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let Java know that you want to include the jar in your classpath (the list of folders and jars it checks for classes).  One way to do this is with the `-cp` command line argument, something like

```
java -cp ".;pathToMyJar\myJar.jar" MyClass
```

Another is to edit the CLASSPATH environment variable in your OS to include your jar.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to place the jar fiel inside the windows folder if you are doing it in a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question contains a lot of question signs and few information.

If you are using java.io.File to open jar as a regular file this jar should not be in lib directory. You just have to provide correct path in file system.

If however you are just trying to use jar as a part of your application it should be in classpath. Use either command line `java -cp myjar.jar` MyMainClass`or put full path to this jar to global environment variable`CLASSPATH`.